# oauth2 authentication failing when called from google cloud function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0, pygsheets

I am trying to create a google cloud function that is called when a user clicks a button in google sheets. This function goes through the data and updates another sheet. I have been using pygsheets to do this but I would like to use google cloud functions so that anyone can update the sheet without emailing me to open a terminal and run the script.

My initial error message says that when i run `pygsheets.authorize()` that this method is trying to write in a read only file system. I have tried to make my own custom credentials but have gotten nowhere with them. I have [linked the conversation](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/issues/385#issuecomment-552698566) I had with the maintainer of the pygsheet project.

I am self taught and thus would happily take any advice on how to resolve this issue. I would like to keep using pygsheets if possible as I have not seen any python google sheets tools on par with it. Please help this issue has stumped me for a couple of weeks.